# How to get element's absolute position in google doc via app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm working on a Google Doc related add-on, and would like to know certain element's absolute position from the page where element is located.

For example, if there are 3 paragraphs in page 1, I'd like to know the leftOffset and topOffset for the starting point of paragraph 3 based on the whole page 1.

Is there a way to do this by any chance?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you could try [`Class Body`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body) which you can access `getAttributes()`, `getMarginTop()`, `getMarginRight()`, `getMarginLeft()`, `getMarginBottom()` and `getChild(childIndex)`. AFAIK, these are the  only methods that you could use to what you want to get. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot! But I think these margins are only for the body itself. I'm hoping to find a way to get the margin for smaller elements inside a doc (or child element of the body to be more specific), eg a particular paragraph or a particular table element. Any thought? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't really have the position of an object in google script but you could have

the id of your element (y pos) and the offset where your cursor is (x pos) :

```
var cursor = doc.getCursor();
var element = cursor.getElement();

var y_position = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getChildIndex(e);
var x_position = cursor.getOffset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked with developer support from Google, and here is the answer I got from them:

"The information regarding an image's absolute offset position is not directly exposed.

It's possible for you to calculate it yourselves, but doing so effectively requires running through the rendering logic for the document. You would need to look at the attributes of all the preceding elements, font metrics, calculate line lengths & wrapping, etc. Not trivial, but possible.

You might be able to take a shortcut by exporting the doc to a format like PDF or docx. Not sure about the capabilities of those formats, but there may be libraries that can do those calculations for you. Might be slightly lossy."

Hope this could help anyone with the same question :)